# hex to dec string in Python with base 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, casting

I have a string in Python which represents a hex val

```
my_hex_str = "000004fc"
```

How do I convert it into an int ?
04fc = 1276 in DEC

Tried

```
my_dec = int(my_hex_str)
```

But did not work, it gives me

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '000004fc'
```

Comment: Read [the documentation for int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the base:

```
>>> int("000004fc", 16)
1276
```